# Как скрыть/показать элементы в зависимости от значения select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Добрый день. В js я только начинаю. Имеется код скрытия/показа поля в зависимости от выбранного селекта. Он работает, при выборе Конверт до 300 гр., поле выбора веса скрывается. Но не скрывается label "Вес груза". И потом, опять при выборе значения "Конверт до 300 гр" поле выбора веса остается статичным.Помогите пожалуйста советом, что дописать нужно? Спасибо большое.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <label for="cargo_name">Название груза</label>
        <select name="cargo_name" id="cargo_name" class="form-control">
            <option value="letter_300">Конверт до 300 гр.</option>
            <option value="docs">Документы</option>
            <option value="parcels">Посылки</option>
        </select>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12">
    <label for="cargo_weight">Вес груза</label>
        <select name="cargo_weight" id="cargo_weight" class="form-control">
           <option value="0.3">0.3</option>
           <option value="1">1</option>
           <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#cargo_name').change(function() {
            if ($("#cargo_name :selected").val()!="0") {
                $("#cargo_weight").css("display", "inline-block");
            } 
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: а что должно быть? вроде все работает

Comment: @L. Vadim не скрывается название поля "Вес груза". И потом, опять при выборе значения "Конверт до 300 гр" поле выбора веса остается статичным и не скрывается.

Comment: у меня все работает правельно, просто у вас немного нужно подправить javascript

Comment: @L. Vadim да. так вот я прошу помочь...

Comment: что должно быть после выбора груза? 
распишите логику

Comment: если я выбираю "Конверт до 300 гр" поле и название поля "Вес груза" скрывается. Выбираю значение "Документы" поле и название поля "Вес груза" появляется. Так же и "Посылки". Когда поле "Вес груза" отображается, мне нужно опять выбрать "Конверт до 300 гр", выбираю, а поле "Вес груза" не исчезает.

Comment: Проверьте ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Убирает `Вес груза` когда выбранно `Конверт до 300 гр.`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#cargo_name').change(function() {
  if($(this).val() === "docs" || $(this).val() === "parcels")
   {
    $("#cargo_weight").css("display", "block");
   }
   else
   {
    $("#cargo_weight").css("display", "none");
   }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12">
    <label for="cargo_name">Название груза</label>
        <select name="cargo_name" id="cargo_name" class="form-control">
            <option value="-----">----- ----</option>
            <option value="letter_300">Конверт до 300 гр.</option>
            <option value="docs">Документы</option>
            <option value="parcels">Посылки</option>
        </select>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12">
   <div  id="cargo_weight" >
    <label for="cargo_weight">Вес груза</label>
        <select name="cargo_weight" class="form-control">
           <option value="0.3">0.3</option>
           <option value="1">1</option>
           <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо. все круто.